# How to bind the hid-generic driver to an hid interface that's taken by a different hid driver?

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel-modules, bind, hid

Short background on the issue I'm facing. I'm working on implementing a simultaneous UART/I2C operation using a usb bridge, the FT260. The chip relies on HID reports to provide these functionalities.
Plugged in, the hid-generic driver detects two interfaces, 0 and 1, the first is for I2C and the second is for UART. Currently, I have the [FT260 driver](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/hid/hid-ft260.c?h=v5.13) supporting I2C *only* loaded as a module (i.e., **hid-ft260**) and it works fine. Then the latter takes over hid-generic and I think the **usbhid** is responsible for that. `lsusb -t` returns:

```
|__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
|__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

`dmesg` shows the following during boot-up:

```
hid-generic 0003:0403:6030.0001: hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [FTDI FT260] on usb-xhci-hcd.1.auto-1.2
hid-generic 0003:0403:6030.0002: hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [FTDI FT260] on usb-xhci-hcd.1.auto-1.2
ft260 0003:0403:6030.0001: hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [FTDI FT260] on usb-xhci-hcd.1.auto-1.2/input
ft260 0003:0403:6030.0002: hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [FTDI FT260] on usb-xhci-hcd.1.auto-1.2/input
```

For UART, I had to use an application that works with the hid-generic. While the driver for I2C can be extended to support UART, maybe as virtual COM port, but it's not that trivial (at least I think) plus I have a working code that I'd like to use and carry on with the rest of the project.

When I try to unbind the interface UART using the following command:

```
echo -n 0003:0403:6030.0002 > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/ft260/unbind
```

I can see the binding is gone.
However, when I try to bind the exact interface (if 1) to **hid-generic**

```
echo -n 0003:0403:6030.0002 > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-generic/bind
```

I get:

```
-bash: echo: write error: No such device
```

hid-generic gets loaded automatically (hot-plug) though when I unload the module hid-ft260 using:

```
modprobe -r hid-ft260
```

It sounds like the usbhid locks to a single sub driver at a time based on PID and VID, but could be something else.
If you have insights on bypassing this, that'll be very helpful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I add the answer that worked for me. So it turns out that **hid-generic** provides a callback function (kernel 5.4.70) namely `hid_generic_match`that accepts a second bool parameter `ignore_special_driver`. If this is set (ignore_special_driver=1), then the matching function returns `true` and the probing takes place. After this, the **hid-generic** allows to link with the ft260's uart interface. **usbhid** had nothing to do with it after all.

For my setup, the modules **hid-generic** and **hid-ft260** start after rebooting with **hid-ft260** controlling both interfaces. So to work around the issue posted above I do the following:

```
echo 1 > /sys/module/hid/parameters/ignore_special_drivers
echo -n "0003:0403:6030.0002" > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/ft260/unbind
```

Because of hotplug, hid-generic is probed successfully on the available HID-UART interface:

```
hid-generic 0003:0403:6030.0002: hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [FTDI FT260] on usb-xhci-hcd.1.auto-1.2/input1
```

The binding can also be checked as:

```
root@root:~# ls /sys/bus/hid/drivers/ft260/
0003:0403:6030.0001  bind  module  new_id  uevent  unbind
root@root:~# ls /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-generic/
0003:0403:6030.0002  bind  module  new_id  uevent  unbind
```

A `udev` rule can be created to automate this.

**Remark**: If `ignore_special_driver=1` before probing **hid-ft260**, the ft260 driver would not bind to either interface, despite the matching VID and PID.